# R JuliaCall crashes when building from Bookdown

Tags: r, julia, bookdown

I am trying to use R-Bookdown for building joint .pdf and html site. According to the manual it should be possible to integrate Julia code. However R does not find the Julia `sys.so`. The problem is explained here: https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/99 without any solution provided.

The command:

```
Rscript -e "bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')"
```

Gives this result:

```
Julia version 1.0.3 at location /usr/bin will be used.
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/sys.so"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/sys.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Something is obviously wrong in the construction of the search path for `sys.so`. Appreciating any assistance!